# В массив добавляется input#title, вместо значения, введенного в input

Tags: javascript, html, массивы

```js
const input = document.getElementById("title")
const createBtn = document.getElementById("create")
const checkBtn = document.getElementById("check")
const checkInput = document.getElementById("checkInput")

const Name =['lera']
createBtn.onclick = function(){
    Name.push(input)
    console.log(Name)
    input.value = ""
    
}
checkBtn.onclick = function(){
    console.log(Name.includes(checkInput))
}
```

Суть программы в том что ты вводишь в `input` текст, нажимаешь на кнопку и этот текст добавляется в массив. Но загвоздка в том, что когда после добавления элемента в массив я вывожу массив в консоль, то получаю это: `['lera', input#title]`.

Что такое этот **input#title** и как пофиксить код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Name.push(input) // добавляете в массив сам input, а не его значение (input.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы добавляете в массив сам элемент **input**, а не значение, которое введено.

Для доступа к введенному значению, необходимо обратиться к свойству **value** элемента:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('title');
const createBtn = document.getElementById("create");

const Name = ['lera']
createBtn.onclick = function() {
  Name.push(input.value)
  console.log(Name)
}
```

```html
<input id="title" />
<button id="create">Жмяк</button>
```